# How are objects classified as values in Scala?

Tags: scala

Keep reading this how objects are treated as or are values, which confuses me, in Scala. I do get how objects can have attributes or methods that can return values, but other than that I cannot see how an object is something is a value.

Comment: An object declared with the `object` keyword in Scala is really a singleton instance of some class, or an object. Objects are values - almost everything in Scala or Java code is an object, not including primitives

Answer (score 4):

Consider value `42`.

We can give it a name

```
val x: Int = 42
```

We can pass it as an argument to a function

```
val f: Int => Int = x => x + 1
f(42)
```

We can return it from a function as a result

```
val g: Int => Int = x => 42
g(1)
```

Now consider singleton `object Foo`.

We can give it a name

```
val x: Foo.type = Foo
```

We can pass it as an argument to a function

```
val f: Foo.type => String = x => x.toString
f(Foo)
```

We can return it from a function as a result

```
val g: Int => Foo.type = x => Foo
g(1)
```

`Foo` is a value in the same sense `42` is a value.

Answer (score 3):

> I do get how objects can have attributes or methods that can return values

Well, then you already know everything you need to know:

```scala
class Foo {
  def bar = this
}

val quux = new Foo

quux.bar
//=> Playground$Foo@deadbeef: Foo
```

[[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NnrDEQGFSA6l9SmrzlC1qw.js)]

You said, you get that objects can have methods that return values. Well, here we have an object `quux` with a method `bar` that returns the object itself. Since you said that methods return values, and this method returns the object itself, the object must obviously be a value.

We can do it even simpler, though. Do you agree that `23` is a value? Well, `23` is an object. It is an instance of the [`scala.Int`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) class.